# why my proto file bytes type generate to c++ type is string *？

Tags: c++, string, protocol-buffers

[image: my pic1]

[image: my pic2]

proto code

```
package mytest;

message RTKEY
{
   optional int64     id1  = 1;
   optional int64     id2  = 2;
};

message ControlArea
{
   optional RTKEY id        = 1;
   optional string name      = 2;
   optional RTKEY parent    = 3;
   optional int32 level     = 4;
   optional bool  remove_fg = 5;
}
```

c++ code

```
::mytest::RTKEY* id_;
::std::string* name_;
::mytest::RTKEY* parent_;
::google::protobuf::int32 level_;
bool remove_fg_;
```

why my proto file bytes type generate to c++ type is string *？

Answer (score 0):

This is documented here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar

Fields of bytes type will get the C++ type string. Your example though, does not include any bytes type fields. The std::string is a quite convenient container for storing an array of bytes.

Comment: std::string  std::string * is the same type?